# Filter Microsoft Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I have a small question related with the Microsoft Graph API, regarding specific functions like filter/search. I use the 'users' endpoint and what I want is to be able to combine the basic filter function (e.g.: `startsWith(displayName,Name)`) that is set via the query params of the request, with a 'Not Equal' function.

What I tried so far looks something like this:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=startswith(displayName,'Surname%20FirstName')%20ne%20'Specific%20Name'
```

As an exception I get back:

> Request_UnsupportedQuery

Does this mean that the specific endpoint does not support `Not Equal` function or my request does not conform with what the API expects?

Here is a [small example](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/using-optional-query-parameters-with-microsoft-graph-api-part-two/) where I found the search function used as I said, but for another end point.

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0#filter-parameter):

> Note: The following $filter operators are not supported for Azure AD resources: `ne`, `gt`, `ge`, `lt`, `le`, and `not`. The contains string operator is currently not supported on any Microsoft Graph resources.

Comment: Hey :) thank you for the response. But if those functions are not supported is there any way to achieve what I want without being force to make a filtering operation on the client ?

Comment: No, you'll need to filter client side.